# Creating a multiple subpages in Wordpress with the same content and template as the parent

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Is there a way to generate multiple new pages in wordpress with the same template, content and everything else except page name in Wordpress. The names of the new pages will be from a list of about 300 cities.

I found a plugin called BulkPress where i can insert the list and it generates the pages but with the default template and no content.

EDIT: Sorry i missed one important thing!
All the pages need to be subpages of one already made parent page and the template and content needs to be copied from that parent!

Answer (score 2):

You could create this with programmatically. Put below code in your active template `functions.php`. It will insert 300 pages.

```
wp_insert_post( array $postarr, bool $wp_error = false, bool $fire_after_hooks = true )
```

e.g.,

```
foreach($i=1;$i<=300;$i++){
    $my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( "Your post Title" ),
      'post_type'      => 'page',
      'post_content'  => "Post Content Goes here",
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'page_template'  => 'template-blog.php',
      'post_author'    => get_user_by( 'id', 1 )->user_id,
    );
// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm new for wordpress and php is not my strongest suit. Could you 
explain in more depth. Where to put the second code block? If i have a JS array of cities (var cities = [Berlin, Paris, London, Barcelona, etc..]) how do i incorporate it to the code to get the page titles from it?

Also can i specify the parent for the new pages?